# Apply an equation to a dataframe using coefficients from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-wrangling

I have to 2 dataframes:

`input_df`

```
Apples    Pears   Peaches   Grapes
12        23       0         4
10        0        0         4
12        16       12        5
6         0        0         11
```

`coefficients_df`

```
Fruit       n    w1      w2
Apples      2    0.4     40
Pears       1    0.1     43
Peaches     1    0.6     51
Grapes      2    0.5     11
```

I'm trying to apply an equation `y = w2*(1-exp(-w1*input_df^n))`to `input_df`. The equation takes coefficients from `coefficients_df`

This is what I tried:

```
# First map coefficients_df to input_df
merged_df = input_df.merge(coefficients_df.pivot('Fruit'), on=['Apples','Pears','Peaches','Grapes'])

# Apply function to each row
output_df = merged_df.apply(lambda x: w2*(1-exp(-w1*x^n))
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of what you are trying to do, since showing us something that doesn't work tell us little about what it is supposed to do

Comment: I'm trying to apply an equation to input_df. That equation uses coefficients which are stored in coefficients_df

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Comment: It's dummy data, havent really calculated an output. But your solution seems correct :)

Comment: @star_it8293 OK, thanks for the feedback, you might want to add my output once you confirm that it's valid ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple index alignment:

```
coeff = coefficients_df.set_index('Fruit')

y = coeff['w2']*(1-np.exp(-coeff['w1']*input_df**coeff['n']))
```

Output:

```
      Apples     Pears    Peaches     Grapes
0  40.000000  38.68887   0.000000  10.996310
1  40.000000   0.00000   0.000000  10.996310
2  40.000000  34.31845  50.961924  10.999959
3  39.999978   0.00000   0.000000  11.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcasting to get value from `df_input`:

```
# df1 is input_df
# df2 is coefficients_df
col_idx = (df1.columns.to_numpy() == df2['Fruit'].to_numpy()[:, None]).argmax(axis=1)
x = df1.values[df1.index, col_idx]

y = df2['w2']*(1-np.exp(-df2['w1']*x**df2['n']))
```

Output:

```
>>> y
0    40.000000
1     0.000000
2    50.961924
3    11.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Im a bit late to the party but here you go.

```
import numpy as np
results = {}
for col in input_df.columns:
    coefs = coefficients_df.loc[coefficients_df['Fruit'] == col].iloc[0,1:]
    y = np.array(coefs.w2*(1-np.exp(-coefs.w1*(input_df[col]**coefs.n))))
    results[col] = y
```

and for me the output is

```
{'Apples': array([40.       , 40.       , 40.       , 39.9999777]),
 'Pears': array([38.68886972,  0.        , 34.31844973,  0.        ]),
 'Peaches': array([ 0.        ,  0.        , 50.96192412,  0.        ]),
 'Grapes': array([10.99630991, 10.99630991, 10.99995901, 11.        ])}
```